# IIS 7 ignores MapPageRoute without file extensions

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-routing

I have a Project, where I want to use the asp.net Routing function. Therefore I added some routes in my global.asax Application_start.

This works fine on my Windows 7 SP1, but when I deploy the Application to my W2K8 R2 Live Server I only get 404's when using the URLs. If I add a /default.aspx at the end of the URLs the pages get displayt correctly.

The IIS seems to ignore the URLs without a file extension.

Working on Local Server but 404 on Live server:

```
http://website/list/123/Test
```

Working on both Servers:

```
http://website/list/123/Test/index.aspx
```

How can I get the Live server to use the extension less urls?

Comment: FIXED: I found the missing Config on the live server: I just added <system.webServer><modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules></system.webServer> to the web.config of the W2K8 and now the URLs are all  working. But I don't know, why these settings are enabled on my local System...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't forget to add the following in your web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I had the opposite problem (routes with a dot in them were being treated as static content, and then the "document" wasn't being found). But this fixed my problem...until I found that other static content wasn't getting loaded when ran from the server due to identity management.

Comment: I have a need to route a non-existed url ended with file extension ".pdf". and your solution fixed my problem. and chatgpt added that: "enabling this setting can have performance implications for your website, as it may cause unnecessary processing for static files like images or CSS files. So, use it with caution and test the performance impact on your website."

Comment: My very 1st attempt to solve this is by asking ChatGPT, but the solution provided by it cannot fixed my problem. So, after some searching in google, I found this solution. and I gonna go back to ChatGPT to teach it about this info.