# Why is MapPageRoute / RedirectToRoute working on dev machine but not on production server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have a regular webforms project (non-MVC) and I successfully implemented a MapPageRoute and RedirectToRoute scenario.  The page routing is done by database lookups because I am translating query strings (e.g. ?filter=112 to /my-friendly-url).  It works nicely on my development machine running VWD 2010 Express and the included ASP.NET Development Server.  The ASP.NET version is 4.0.30319.272.  However, when I run the project on the production (iis7) box, I get page not found errors on the mapped pages.  The rest of the site/pages run fine.  My gut feeling is that the page handling is the root of the issue, but I can't figure what it is or why.  It may have to do with how iis7 handles a directory vs. a filename and the interference that may arise from my program routing physical .aspx to directory-style names.  My iis7 & web.config knowledge is a bit weak in this area.

Here an excerpt of my global.asax:

```
   void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      // Code that runs on application startup
      RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
   }

   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
      routes.Clear();
      routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;
      routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); //ignore axd files, prevents javascript/routing collisions
      routes.MapPageRoute("Education", "{category}/{section}", "~/product/education/default.aspx");
      routes.MapPageRoute("EducationLanding", "{category}", "~/product/education/default.aspx");
   }
```

Web.config: Handlers section of

```
 <handlers>
     <remove name="StaticFile" />
     <remove name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0" />
     <add verb="*" path="ajax/*.ashx" name="Ajax" type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory, Ajax" />
     <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
     <add name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
     <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />  
  </handlers>
```

Thanks in advance,
John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into page handling led me to the modules section of the web.config and I found my answer here on SO ([IIS 7 ignores MapPageRoute without file extentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393290/iis-7-ignores-mappageroute-without-file-extentions)).  Why I didn't find this in all my previous searches I shall not know.  Behold:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Thank you @Christoph

Answer (score 0):

All this is good but do not forget the server needs to be restarted to trigger the  Application_Start of your global.asax

Comment: It appears that this question already has an accepted answer which explains that the solution required more than just a server reboot.