# RouteMapping works on development server but results in 404 in production

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the following code in Global.asax, in a web site project with webforms, not an MVC application:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("Documents", "documents/{document-id}/", "~/GetDocument.aspx");
}
```

The route mapping works correctly on my dev environment which runs IIS Express, but in production it returns a 404 error.

The server runs IIS 7 and has almost identical web.config-files. I haven't been able to identify any changes between the dev web.config and the production one that might be the cause.

How come my route mappings work in my dev environment but not in my production environment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is MapPageRoute / RedirectToRoute working on dev machine but not on production server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660366/why-is-mappageroute-redirecttoroute-working-on-dev-machine-but-not-on-producti)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried specifying runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true in web.config ?

```
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
```

There are existing queries related to this in StackOverflow: 
(1) [IIS 7 ignores MapPageRoute without file extentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393290/iis-7-ignores-mappageroute-without-file-extentions)
(2) [Why is MapPageRoute / RedirectToRoute working on dev machine but not on production server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660366/why-is-mappageroute-redirecttoroute-working-on-dev-machine-but-not-on-producti)